# How do I embed my own custom form on Mail Chimp?

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I'm trying to embed a form I created using Mail chimp on my WordPress Website, however I have no idea where I can get the embed code for the form I created.

First Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kBgRgAXG7Y

Latest Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVfVDnfci08

Answer (score 0):

There doesnt seem to be an embed code for that, but try iframing it, I would do this.

```
<iframe src="http://successionobsession.us7.list-manage1.com/subscribe?u=ed86236dd561ebae1fcef65a8&id=cdcfd9a4db" width="600px" height ="600px"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

You can put that in the page HTML code or as a widget.

Comment: Thanks dude It worked, where did you get the code from though?

Comment: The link comes from the "Signup form URL" - it redirects to there.The link comes from the "Signup form URL" (eepurl thing) - it redirects to there.

Comment: Please check my most recent video, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please try     `<iframe src="http://successionobsession.us7.list-manage1.com/subscribe?u=ed86236dd561ebae1fcef65a8&id=cdcfd9a4db" width="600px" height ="600px" style="min-width: 10px !important;"" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Comment: #Jean-Pierre Coetzee Still same results

Comment: it is most likely in your stylesheet then, just look around, you should find it somewhere. search for the min-width tab you disabled in your video.

Comment: #Jean-Pierre Coetzee Thank you for all your time but I got it all figured out.